# How to register for Oracle TAF callbacks?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

In my C Application there is a way to register for the Fail over callback in Oracle when it is setup with TAF. When the TAF is correctly setup, it gives the callback to the application when the failover is detected. Application has to sent the retry command.

My Question is how we should handle that in java?

Currently I create the database connection as follows.

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.25.40.253:1521:ora11g", "sujith", "sujith123");
```

In the production implementation there will be 2 database URLs for primary and backup. In the OCI case, it is setup in the tnsnames.ora file.

Please help.

Comment: I think in case of Java you should use UCP. https://martincarstenbach.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/playing-with-application-continuity-in-rac-12c/.

Comment: The Oracle docs are instructive:  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/ocitaf.htm#JJDBC28838